# Shortening nvme timeout to fail _earlier_ - implications?

Tags: linux, timeout, nvme

On the VMware Workstation virtualization hosting platform, using a Linux kernel, I am regularly facing

```
[ 2181.746685] nvme nvme0: I/O 0 QID 4 timeout, completion polled
```

I suspect that this is due to a defect in the implementation of the virtual NVMe controller / the VMware virtual platform.

Alas, every time this occurs, the system is more or less blocked for 30 seconds. Given that this virtual controller effectively talks to a very fast real SSD that's just way too long.

I am now considering tuning the Linux NVMe module options, `cat /sys/module/nvme_core/parameters` to decrease(!) the timeout to, say, 2 seconds - after all, this is a really fast SSD which is all but maxed out, so if the NVMe command does not complete within 2 seconds, something other than that suspected virtual NVMe controller is off.

What are the drawbacks of going from 30 seconds on `io_timeout` to 2 seconds? I expect things to fail *faster*, which basically means that any failure will come faster, which means that any recovery mechanism will be triggered faster.

I have seen documentation for cloud vendors where they suggest that `io_timeout` be set to infinity on their platforms, but what applies to *their platform* is not necessarily the right thing to do for *my VMware Workstation platform*?